# WordPress : Why image is not saved in media library?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, plugins

I am creating a plugin to upload an image into media library.

But i am unable to store it. Help to sort out.

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name:  ****
    */
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_file_upload');
    function my_file_upload() {
            $uploaddir = '/uploads';
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            echo "<p>";
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                 echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                } else {
                   echo "Upload failed";
                }
                echo "</p>";
                echo '<pre>';
                echo 'Hiiiiii';
                print_r($_FILES);
                print "</pre>";
                echo"<imgsrc=$_FILES[userfile][tmp_name]>";
                ?>
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
                    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
                </form>
            <?php       
                }
?>
```

I have been working on it from last few hours and searched a lot but no results :(

Comment: Any error you got ?

Comment: lemme show you.

File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.

Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Desert.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpE6D.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 845941
        )

)

But it doesn't update the media Library with this image

Comment: Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload file using `move_uploaded_file` function, but it does not display in WordPress media library, because file name is not there in database yet, so you have to use WordPress function as below.

PHP:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('userfile', $post_id);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="file-upload" />
```

So, now you should get uploaded image in WordPress media.

Comment: It's not working Yet. :(

where to assign $post_id???


It Neither attachs file :(

Comment: `$post_id` - the media is associated with. If you don't want this media attached to a specific post, you can pass 0.

Comment: No its not working yet, can you write the whole edited code in one script

Comment: Here, we can help you to give you suggestions, we do not provide service to write whole code for you, i clearly mentioned above to use `media_handle_upload` function, did you try to debug my code ? without your efforts no one will write code for you.

Comment: @Daniel, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173197/upload-multiple-files-with-media-handle-upload Read it if it helps.